# "Extend" relationship in a relational database

Tags: database-design, performance, normalization

**Hello,**
I'm currently trying to apply the most efficient way to store an "extend" relationship between entities in a relational database.

For the sake of example, lets say we have the following simplified entities:

- `User`
- `Student` (extends `User`)
- `Teacher` (extends `User`)

`User` contains attributes which apply to both `Student` and `Teacher`. Both `Student` and `Teacher` contain custom attributes which are unique to them.

The first thing that comes to mind is to create a single table with columns for all singular data (i.e. except one-to-many fields):

```
User
-------------
User ID
First name
Last name
Student class
Teacher office no.
Teacher description
...
```

This however won't be very efficient from a storage perspective, because:

- the majority of rows will contain students, with a small number of teachers
- teachers will have much more unique columns, which would waste space in students' rows

It would be more efficient to replicate relationships between the entities:

```
User
-------------
User ID
First name
Last name
...


Student
-------------
User ID
Student class
...


Teacher
-------------
User ID
Teacher office no.
Teacher description
...
```

So my questions are:

1. Is the above concern taking it too far, i.e. should we leave storage efficiency to the database engine?
2. Is splitting the entities into 3 tables still OK in terms of normalization?
3. If it's not a good approach, how would you recommend to treat "extend" relationships in a relational database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user can't be both a teacher and a student, then you're looking at a straightforward supertype/subtype problem. (I'm using *supertype* and *subtype* in their relational database design sense, not in their object-oriented programming sense.) You're right to store in "students" only those attributes that describe students, and to store in "teachers" only those attributes that describe teachers.

```
-- Supertype: users
create table users (
  user_id integer not null unique,
  user_type char(1) not null 
    check (user_type in ('T', 'S')),
  -- other user columns
  primary key (user_id, user_type)
);

-- Subtype: students
create table students_st (
  user_id integer not null,
  user_type char(1) not null default 'S'
    check (user_type = 'S'),
  locker_num integer not null unique 
    check (locker_num > 0),
  -- other student columns
  primary key (user_id, user_type),
  foreign key (user_id, user_type) 
    references users (user_id, user_type) 
    on delete cascade
);

-- Subtype: teachers
create table teachers_st (
  user_id integer not null,
  user_type char(1) not null default 'T'
    check (user_type = 'T'),
  office_num char(4),
  -- other teacher columns
  primary key (user_id, user_type),
  foreign key (user_id, user_type) 
    references users (user_id, user_type) 
    on delete cascade
);

create view teachers as 
select u.user_id,
       u.user_type,
       -- other user columns
       t.office_num
       -- other teacher columns
from users u
inner join teachers_st t on (u.user_id = t.user_id);

create view students as 
select u.user_id,
       u.user_type,
       -- other user columns
       s.locker_num
       -- other student columns
from users u
inner join students_st s on (u.user_id = s.user_id);
```

At this point, you'd also do whatever your dbms requires to make these two views updatable—triggers, rules, whatever. Application code inserts, updates, and deletes from the views, not from the base tables.

Comment: I didn't know that this was being referenced to as `supertype/subtype` in the RDBMS world. This will allow me to research it further, but the proposed solution should work great - thank you very much!<br />Regarding views - I planned to define them, but adding triggers on top of them will ease it up consistently - thank you for the suggestion, much appreciated.